# Sympy not solving a ODE correctly?

Tags: python, math, sympy, symbolic-math

I want to solve the ode f´´(x) + k*f(x) = 0.
which is a trivial ODE to solve (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=f%60%60%28x%29+%2B+kf%28x%29%3D0)

my code is

```
from sympy import * 
x,t,k,L,C1,C2 = symbols("x,t,k,L,C1,C2")
f=symbols('f', cls=Function)
g=symbols('g', cls=Function)

Fx = f(x).diff(x)
Fxx = f(x).diff(x,x)
Gtt = g(t).diff(t,t)
Gt = g(t).diff(t)


BC1 = 0
BC2 = L


Eq1_k_positive = dsolve(Eq1.subs(k,-k))
display(Eq1_k_positive)
```

Not really sure why I don't get the solution that I should get. and no its not the same when I use BCs that would get me a result I get 0 since I don't get the sin cos equation. any tips on what's not correct?

Comment: `Eq1` is not defined in the code you've pasted

Comment: Eq1 = Eq(Fxx-k*f(x),0)

Answer (score 1):

This is your differential equation:

```
In [18]: k, x = symbols('k, x')

In [19]: f = Function('f')

In [20]: eq = Eq(f(x).diff(x, 2) + k*f(x), 0)

In [21]: eq
Out[21]: 
           2          
          d           
k⋅f(x) + ───(f(x)) = 0
           2          
         dx
```

This is the solution returned by SymPy:

```
In [22]: dsolve(eq)
Out[22]: 
                ____           ____
           -x⋅╲╱ -k        x⋅╲╱ -k 
f(x) = C₁⋅ℯ          + C₂⋅ℯ
```

That solution is correct for any nonzero complex number `k`.

There can be many equivalent forms to represent the general solution of an ODE. SymPy will choose a different form here if you specify something about the symbol `k` such as that it is positive:

```
In [24]: k = symbols('k', positive=True)

In [25]: eq = Eq(f(x).diff(x, 2) + k*f(x), 0)

In [26]: eq
Out[26]: 
           2          
          d           
k⋅f(x) + ───(f(x)) = 0
           2          
         dx           

In [27]: dsolve(eq)
Out[27]: f(x) = C₁⋅sin(√k⋅x) + C₂⋅cos(√k⋅x)
```

This solution is also correct for any nonzero complex number `k` but will only be returned if `k` is declared positive because it is only for positive `k` that there is any reason to prefer the `sin/cos` form to the `exp` form.

Comment: Thanks! But i still have a problem with the boundary conditions. if i use:    Eq3 = Eq(Fxx+k*f(x),0) and then Eq1_k_positive = dsolve(Eq3,f(x),ics={f(0):0, f(L):0})
display(Eq1_k_positive) i will still get 0. any idea on how to fix this?